# php mysql get data in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hello i want get data in array from the database, i have this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM nat WHERE village = '$village'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$prname1=array();

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
 
    $prname1[]=$row['id_source'];

  }
```

if call print_r

```
print_r($prname1);
```

get back this value:

```
Array ( [0] => 30000 [1] => 30002 [2] => 30003 )
```

I need values like this:

```
[ [0 => 30000], [0 => 30002], [0 => 30003], ]
```

how to?
Thanks

I try more solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap another array around the value when pushing onto the result array.

```
$prname1[] = [$row['id_source']];
```